# Change JMS settings with Glassfish and Spring

Tags: spring, glassfish, jms, spring-jms, openmq

In our project we use Glassfish v3.1.2.2 with a ConnectionFactory bound as "jms/ConnectionFactory" and a Queue bound as "jms/Queue". Both are created in the glassfish admin console:

The Spring config is implemented this way:

```
@Bean
public JndiTemplate jndiTemplate() {
    JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
    props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
    props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
    props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
    props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
    jndiTemplate.setEnvironment(props);

    return jndiTemplate;
}


@Bean
public JndiObjectFactoryBean connectionFactory() {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean connectionFactory = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    connectionFactory.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate());
    connectionFactory.setJndiName("jms/ConnectionFactory");

    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy connectionFactoryProxy() {
    return new TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy((ConnectionFactory) connectionFactory().getObject());
}

@Bean
public JndiObjectFactoryBean destination() {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate());
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName("jms/Queue");
    return jndiObjectFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
    jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory((ConnectionFactory) connectionFactory().getObject());
    jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination((Destination) destination().getObject());
    return jmsTemplate;
}

@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer() {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactoryProxy());
    listenerContainer.setDestination((Destination) destination().getObject());
    listenerContainer.setMessageListener(messageDispatcher);
    listenerContainer.setSessionTransacted(true);
    listenerContainer.setTransactionManager(jtaTransactionManager());
    return listenerContainer;
}
```

Everything works fine so far, message will be sent to and consumed from the queue without any problems. Rolling back messages wit a RuntimeException works, too.

The problem is, how to change some fundamental settings, like RedeliveryAttempts or RedeliveryInterval from the Activation Spec. I cant find any solution to change this with Spring only with MDB. Is there a way to do this in Glassfishs admin console or in Spring configuration? Did I have to use some different implementation or is it not possible over all?

Hope anybody can help.
Thanks in advance,
Danny

Answer (score 1):

Through some trial and error I found the following, which works on Glassfish 4.

```
@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
    jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);  //may be necessary if using topic
    jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName("topicname");
    jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    return jmsTemplate;
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    try {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiFactory = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jndiFactory.setJndiName("jms/ConnectionFactory");
        jndiFactory.setResourceRef(true);  //adds java:comp/env/ prefix
        jndiFactory.afterPropertiesSet();  //very important, actually causes the object to be loaded

        return (ConnectionFactory) jndiFactory.getObject();

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | NamingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```